# How to run a Visual Studio Code compiled/minified Web build in the browser

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am able to run VS Code development mode in my browser by installing the required packages and running a few commands, but I failed to build a compiled and minified version and run the same in browser.

I am able to run VS Code web development mode in the browser on Ubuntu 20.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev libsecret-1-dev
yarn
yarn watch
./scripts/code-web.sh
```

I'm able to build with the following command, but am missing instructions on how to run a compiled version of VS Code Web in browser.

```
yarn gulp vscode-web-min
```

Can anyone tell me how to or point me to the right documentation?

Comment: Perhaps this page is helping? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs

Comment: I’m not sure what your goal here is but you might want to try code-server out. It’s a vscode on the browser that runs on a server or locally and serves the ui over the browser and runs the code/commands on the computer that is serving the code-server instance

Comment: @JohnD code-server is good but even then there is no documentation about how to build  and minify it to launch. the develop version is more than 50mb when we load in the browser.

Comment: how small do you need it to be? also I think it caches it after the first load so I'm not sure what is the purpose of what you are trying to accomplish but for me, it has worked just fine for personal use. Could you explain more what it is you are trying to achive?

Answer (score 4):

Recently I came across the same question. I found this repo https://github.com/Felx-B/vscode-web which perfectly answers your question. This is not a fork of vscode, but rather a set of helper scripts in order to build vscode web edition.

You should clone this repository and run the following commands in order to build vscode-web.

```
$ yarn build
$ yarn prepare-demo
$ yarn demo
```

Open http://localhost:8080 and you'll see the web version running in your browser. It is limited in features compared to the native or server version. Terminal is disabled and files are served from in-browser file system.